# Datatable com pagination server side

Tags: laravel-5, jquery-datatables, datatable, angular

Procurei muito no Google mas não tive um caminho claro de como fazer uma datatable ( uso angular 2 ) que contenha paginação pelo servidor, ou seka, que a cada página ele fizesse uma requisição individual da mesma.

Todas que vi, faz a requisição php com o back-end, mas traz todos os registros em JSON de uma vez, ou seja, se houver 100.000 linhas ele pega todas elas.

Gostaria de desenvolver uma table que a cada página ( de 30 registros ) fizesse uma requisição para pegar o JSON dos próximos registros.
A parte do back-end é tranquilo, preciso somente de um caminho pra fazer essa páginação no angular, como pedir cada requisição.
Creio que primeiro terei que pegar um total de linhas e fazer a divisão de páginas, depois a casa página fazer uma req http tipo: empresas/2(page)/30 (registros) para retornar os registros daquele intervalo.

Ja fiz isso com o laravel (php) através da paginação nativa dele com bootstrap, mas agora estou fazendo o front-end pelo angular 2 e terei que mudar.

**Atualização:**

conforme a foto, ex do meu back-end:
[image: back-end]

Meu Service para pegar http:(ele funciona no console.log(), mas não estou conseguindo passar a resposta pra uma variável pra depois mandar pra view.
Estou me aventurando agora em Angular, principalmente typescript, estou vendo várias video-aulas e tals mas ta complicado, minha área é PHP.

**Service.ts**

> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'; import {Observable}
>   from 'rxjs/Rx'; //import {Empresa} from '../models/empresas';
>
> // Import RxJs required methods import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
>   //import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
>
> @Injectable() export class EmpresasCrudService {
>         //private commentsUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/empresas';
>
> constructor(private _http: Http) {   }
>
> _endpoint_url: string =
>   'http://localhost/16-11/Sysferaser5.3/public/data/4';
>   getEmpresas(page:number) {
>       return this._http.get(this._endpoint_url + "?page=" + page)
>         .map(response => response.json());   }
>
> }

**empresas-index.component.ts:**

> import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
>
> import { EmpresasCrudService } from
>   './services/empresas-crud.service'; import { Http, Response, Headers,
>   RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
>
> @Component({   selector: 'empresas-index',   templateUrl:
>   'app/cadastros/empresas/empresas-index.component.html' }) export class
>   EmpresasIndexComponent implements OnInit{
>
> ```
> constructor(private dataService: EmpresasCrudService) {
>
> this._service = dataService;   }
> public _service;
> public _data;
> public _total;
> public _page;
>
> getEmps(page: number){
>
>     this._service.getEmpresas(page)
>         .subscribe(
>         people => {this._data = people.data, this._total = people.total},
>         error => console.error('Error: ' + error),
>         () => console.log('Completed!')
>     );
>     this._page = page;
> }
>
> ngOnInit(){
>   this.getEmps(1);
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

**empresa-index.component.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
        Panel title
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    Total: {{ _total }} <br>
    Página: {{ _page }}
    <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of _data">{{item.empresa_id}}</li>
</ul><br><br>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    Panel footer
</div>
```

Comment: Consegui fazer mas surgiu uma dúvida na paginação, mas pra quem quiser ver o código está na outra pergunta:
<https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166128/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-angular-2-server-side> Fiz com a biblioteca que o amigo indicou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semana passada eu estive fazendo alguns estudos, e criei um projeto Rails 5 API JSON com umas 100 linhas, e mandei paginar de 10 em 10.

Depois, fiz um projeto em Angular 2 para ler estas linhas, e pegar os dados e paginar.

Se o que entendi que você quer fazer é o mesmo que eu fiz, este módulo irá facilitar seu trabalho

https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination

No seu Component, crie um método para puxar a quantidade de linhas da API via Service

```
  getPage(page: number) {
    this._data = this.postService.getPosts(page)
      .do((res: any) => {
        this._total = res.json().total;
        this._page = page;
      })
      .map((res: any) => res.json().data);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPage(1);
  }
```

O meu service contém apenas um método buscando os dados da URL da API

```
  _endpoint_url: string = 'http://192.168.2.3:3030/api/v1/posts';
  getPosts(page) {
    return this._http.get(this._endpoint_url + "?page=" + page)
  }
```

Lembrando que sua API deverá conter uma propriedade passando o TOTAL de registros que contém.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu exemplo está feio e mal escrito porque trata-se apenas de testes, estudos, que faço em minha máquina local para aprender, visto que estou desempregado, mas, parar de aprender, jamais :-) !

Comment: Beleza amigo, assim que testar aviso aqui

Comment: Realmente é isso que preciso, mas estou com dificuldades ainda...

Comment: Atualzei a foto do back-end, criei um serviço que faz a requisição ajax...
mas não estou conseguindo entender pra implementar no empresas-index.component -> para mostrar a table

Comment: Compartilhe seu também seu component.ts .html e seu service para verificarmos como você está implementando. Aparentemente seu endPoint está correto, mostrando o total de linhas.

Comment: Depois de tanto pesquisar, deu tudo certo, resolvido a questão, obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Compartilhe como você conseguiu, para que outros possam utilizar este post para resolver caso cheguem ao mesmo problema

Comment: Você não deu +1 na minha resposta, se puder fazer isto, caso ela tenha sido útil, fico grato.